# How to write decorator to store api's data into Redis

Tags: typescript, redis, decorator

I am new to decorators. I want to write a decorator in typescript to store api's data into redis and return data if given key available. A key is combination of input strings like in this case "input1 + input2". "keyIndex" is the array containing which input's string will be included for making the key. The structure is given below

```
@storethis(ttl='', keyIndex=[0,1])
async function getValueFromAPi(input1, input2, ...) {
  
}
```

Comment: You can only use decorators on class methods. Consider using a wrapper function instead.

Comment: @catgirlkelly yes it is the class method